# How to linking to a div in html?

Tags: php, html

I have a list of links and the content of links are in that page, how can I link to a place of the page?

for example:

```
  <div id="div1">
      content    content    content    content    content
  </div>

   <div id="div2">
      content    content    content    content    content
  </div>

   <div id="div3">
          content    content    content    content    content
   </div>
```

How can I link to **div3**

Comment: How do you link to *anything* on a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the `id` for `div3` like this:

```
<a href="#div3">Link to div3</a>

  <div id="div1">
      content    content    content    content    content
  </div>

   <div id="div2">
      content    content    content    content    content
  </div>

   <div id="div3">
          content    content    content    content    content
   </div>
```

**[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)** you can read more about it.

Answer (score 2):

**Use an anchor to refer to your div `ID`.**

```
<a href="#div3">Link to div3</a>
```

You can find some documentation here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aabg020899a.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#name1">link to name1</a>


<a name="name1">Name1</a>
```

Is the original structure from netscape.

Both of these work today.

```
<ul>
<li> <a href="#name1">1</a>
<li> <a href="#name2">2</a>

</ul>

<div style="height:100%" id="name1">Name1</div>
<div style="height:100%" ><a name="name2">Name2</a></div>
```